# Eliminate a file that is already committed in the same commit

Tags: git

=**The situation**

I have some files:  file1,  file2, file3 that I have *already* added and committed (`git commit -m "my commit"`) (Furthermore, I have already push that commit to a repository)

A particular nuance to take into account is that by policy I cannot do another commit. If I have a change, I will add the files to change and do `git commit --amend`.

**The problem**

As I said I already committed file1, file2, file3. Turns out that I now only want file1 in the commit, so I want file2 and file3 out of the commit.

How can I eliminate those files from the commit (ammending the commit not creating another one)?

Comment: "ammending the commit not creating another one" Amending a commit _does_ create another one. Commits are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**: Stage the changes you want to make.  This process is the same for amending the old commit as it would be for creating a new commit.

You want to remove files, so the direct soltuion is `git rm`.  It sounds like you might want the file later, in which case you shoudl give the `--cached` option

```
git rm --cached file2 file3
```

(There are many other ways that will work, or that may work under specific circumstances.)

**Step 2**: amend the commit.  This is simply

```
git commit --amend
```

No matter what changes you're making - in this case removing some files - this will make a new commit and replace the previous commit with it.  It is somewhat important to understand that you can never change what was already committed; by definition, if you want a commit with different content, then you need a new commit.  So the way you worded the question - deleting the file "in the same commit" - is 100% impossible.

Now, that's not only true when you're deleting files; it is always how `--amend` works. So if the policy allows you to amend, then that part is fine.  But the reason the distinction matters is this:

**Step 3**: When you push, address the fact that you rewrote history.  Any time you remove a commit from a branch's history - such as by amending the last commit, which (as noted above) actually replaces that commit with a new one - it's called a history rewrite, and that means a simple push to the remote will not work.

Technically it's easy to do a force push

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

(You should pretty much always use `--force-with-lease` instead of simply `-f`, to avoid clobbering changes you don't even know exist in the event someone else had already pushed to the same branch.)

However, force pushing history rewrites puts any other users of the repo into a bad state that they need to resolve properly to avoid undoing your changes; so you do need to coordinate with anyone else who might have a copy of the branch, to make sure they're (at bare minimum) aware of what you're doing.

You can find more info about the issues of pushing history rewrites on the `git rebase` page, under "recovering from upstream rebase".  (Although you are not rebasing, the issue is the same.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git checkout` to restore your files to how they were before the commit:

```
git checkout HEAD~1 -- file2 file3
```

Then you can use `amend` normally:

```
git commit --amend
```

Remember you'll need to force your push:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Comment: Whoops, meant file2 and file3 - they're the files you want out of the commit. Edited.